# Если изображения не показываются, влияют ли они на скорость загрузки?

Tags: веб-программирование

есть div с 10 изображений
При изначальной загрузкой они скрыты
Появляются когда пользователь кликает на кнопку
Загружаются ли они при первоначальной загрузке или после того как пользователь нажал (

Comment: сразу, а вообще, посмотрите во вкладке Network devtools

Comment: Как именно скрыты?

Comment: @andreymal, а есть разница? чтобы картинка не загружалась нужно ничего не класть в `src`

Comment: @meine вот вы сами разницу и описали, вдруг src заполняется скриптом :)